# How do I change the output of get_the_tag_list()?

Tags: tags

Currently 
 I have this code

```
$tag_list = get_the_tag_list('<ul><li>','</li><li>','</li></ul>');
```

and outputs:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="tag_link">tag_name</a></li>
    ....
</ul>
```

How can I change it so it displays like this?

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="tag_link"><span>tag_name</span></a></li>
    ....
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, from the [`get_the_tag_list()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tag_list) Codex entry:

> - $before
>
>   - (string) (optional) Leading text.
>   - Default: 'Tags: '
> - $sep
>
>   - (string) (optional) String to separate tags.
>   - Default: ', '
> - $after
>
>   - (string) (optional) Trailing text.
>   - Default: None

Since you're using this example:

```
get_the_tag_list('<ul><li>','</li><li>','</li></ul>');
```

...edited to save space...

Modify it as such:

```
get_the_tag_list( '<ul><li><span>', '</span></li><li><span>', '</span></li></ul>' );
```

...should get you what you're after.

**EDIT**

> I think you misunderstood my question. The span is supposed to be in the anchor tags. Your method would output `<li><span><a></a></span></li>`

Sorry about that; I misread the question.

This gets a bit trickier, but is entirely possible. The `get_the_tag_list()` template tag uses `get_the_term_list()`, which has a filter for the term links, called `term_links-$taxonomy` (which for tags would be, `term_links-post_tag`.

So, you could write a filter:

```
function mytheme_filter_post_tag_term_links( $term_links ) {
    $wrapped_term_links = array();
    foreach ( $term_links as $term_link ) {
        $wrapped_term_links[] = '<span>' . $term_link . '</span>';
    }
    return $wrapped_term_links;
}
add_filter( 'term_links-post_tag', 'mytheme_filter_post_tag_term_links' );
```

Note: this will apply to *every* use of `get_the_term_list()` that outputs post tags. Caveat emptor.

Comment: hey there! I think you misunderstood my question. The span is supposed to be in the anchor tags. Your method would output <li><span><a></a></span></li>

Comment: Okay, see updated answer; I indeed has misread your question.

Answer (score 5):

you could use a filter function, added to functions.php of your theme:

```
add_filter('the_tags', 'wp32234_add_span_get_the_tag_list');

function wp32234_add_span_get_the_tag_list($list) {
    $list = str_replace('rel="tag">', 'rel="tag"><span>', $list);
    $list = str_replace('</a>', '</span></a>', $list);
    return $list;
}
```

Comment: thanks, this works only for tags right?

Comment: as far as I can see, this works on `the_tags()` and `get_the_tag_list()`.

Comment: this would make a perfect answer too!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the `echo` before rendering the tags list:

```
<?php echo get_the_tag_list('<h3>' . __( ' Tags:', 'theme_name' ) . '</span></h3>'); ?>
```

Hope this help.