# How to add a class to anchor tags using the get_the_tag_list(); function?

Tags: tags

What's the easiest way to add a class to the anchor tag using the get_the_tag_list() function?

For example by adding;

```
if(get_the_tag_list()) {
echo get_the_tag_list('<ul><li>','</li><li>','</li></ul>');
}
```

Will return something like this;

```
<ul>
<li><a href="tag1">Tag 1</a></li>
<li><a href="tag2">Tag 2</a></li>
 ... 
</ul>
```

I just need something to add a custom class to the anchor. Thank you.

Comment: Check this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/32234/how-do-i-change-the-output-of-get-the-tag-list

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution using a filter:

```
add_filter( "term_links-post_tag", 'add_tag_class');

function add_tag_class($links) {
return str_replace('<a href="', '<a class="myclass" href="', $links);
}
```